# Does a metric tensor imply the existence of orthonormal coordinates?

Tags: metric-spaces, coordinate-systems, orthogonality

I am writing for a non-specialist audience, and I wish to make the claim that "every space endowed with a metric tensor has an orthonormal coordinate system."  In other words, if, in $n$-dimensional space, we have a metric tensor $g_{ij}$, then we can find a coordinate system $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ such that $$g_{ij} = \vec{e}_i\cdot\vec{e}_j = \delta_{ij},$$ where $\vec{e}_i$ is the vector associated with $x_i$.

Is it okay to make this claim, or are there caveats?

Comment: What does it means that a vector is  **''associated'' to $x_i$**?

Comment: Technically, this is the tangent to the curve parameterized as follows: $x_j(t) = t$ if $j=i$, and $x_j(t) = 0$ otherwise.  However, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true *at a point* (such coordinates are called [Riemann normal coordinates](http://users.monash.edu.au/~leo/research/papers/files/lcb96-01.pdf) or [geodesic normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates#Properties) [the former is a set of notes with details of the construction), but not generally true in an extended region, unless the curvature is zero (in a sense this is what curvature is: an obstruction to orthonormal coordinates staying orthonormal.)

One can also specify an orthonormal frame that remains orthonormal and varies smoothly along a smooth curve (as with the [Frenet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) in 3D flat space), but again, curvature prevents one extending this to higher-dimensional objects because it prevents there being a single notion of parallel transport to from one point to another: if your space is curved and you parallel transport a vector along two different curves between the same two points, you in general get two different results.

Comment: Is this true even if the metric has a negative signature?  Or, in that case, are we forced to say that $g_{ij} = \pm\delta_{ij}$?

Comment: Yes, for [pseudo-Riemannian manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) the same local results apply, but since the signature of the metric is invariant under transformations, you will end up with a diagonal quadratic form with a certain fixed number of $+$ and $-$ on the diagonal (the ordering is unimportant, of course, but the number of each is determined).

Comment: Okay: just to be clear, if the metric is pseudo-Riemannian, then, at best, we can find, at each point, a coordinate system such that $g_{ij} = \pm\delta_{ij}$, correct?  Is there a more general name for orthonormal coordinates in this situation?

Comment: Yes. They are still called normal coordinates (the same construction procedure works).